# Change in momentum of a particle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, time

In the formula

Change in momentum $=$ (Force)•(time)

Does the term ‘time’ mean the time for which the change in momentum occurred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Time is the length of the time interval over which the force acts. This is the time interval over which momentum is changed.

Note that force is a vector and time is a number. That makes change in momentum a vector.